# Update single column value for each selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Every time a checkbox is selected, the *UnitsInStock* value for the selected row is supposed to increase by 1. How can I use the *change* event to send the new value back to the database when I click the 'Submit' button?

I have set up a sample on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ILejOdip/13) to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

I'm able to get it working in JSBin thanks to Anup's help. Only issue is with my update url. This is how it's currently formatted:

```
update: {
    url: function (product) {
        return "/Products/Update/" + product.ProductID
        },
        type: "POST"
},
```

I end up with a 500 error. The data does not get sent and the POST URL ends up as this instead:
`http://localhost:4495/Products/Update/undefined`

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you maintain the values of UnitsInStock in an object some thing like this: var obj = {}. On change of checkbox, you can write: obj[selectedProductName] = unitsInStock. Finally on submit button you can extract the values from that object and send it to the database. The selectedProductName and unitsInStock values can be extracted via jquery. Does that help?

Comment: I was of the thinking that some of the functions built into Kendo UI could do the job. I get what you're saying though, let me give that a try.

Comment: Updated the JSBin: http://jsbin.com/ILejOdip/14/edit

Comment: Thanks, it works! I've added a change event to substantiate edits back to the datasource too: [http://jsbin.com/ILejOdip/16/edit](http://jsbin.com/ILejOdip/16/edit). One thing though, I have an issue with my update URL. I've edited my question to show the problem.

Comment: 500 internal error states that its a server side error, either due to mishandling of URL parameters or some exception thrown. Seems to me, the property `ProductID` doesn't exists in the `product` object. Can you try using `console.log(product)` inside the function and see what property it output.

Comment: Have tried `console.log(product)` and it shows up as undefined. How about if I want to append `dataItem.ProductID` to the update URL in the `dataSource`?